# How to render a TextGeometry?

Tags: three.js

TextGoemetry not bring rendered

I've tried many tutorials on the internet, many tutorials on stackoverflow but none of them worked.

```
    var text;
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0xCCCCCC);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 100);
    light.position.set(1, 0, 50);

    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    loader.load('Fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js', function (response) {
         var textGeometry = new TextGeometry('Hello', {
            font:font,
            size: 80,
            height: 10
        });
    });


    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xFF00FF});
    var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
    scene.add(textMesh, light);
    camera.position.z = 20;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    function update() {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    update();
```

I expect the out of the code that it will render the text, but it doesn't

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56575708/4045502). `new TextGeometry` has to be `new THREE.TextGeometry`.

Comment: @prisoner849 it’s not working

Comment: How is it not working when the provided answer has a working example?

Comment: @prisoner849 somehow it worked. Don’t knowing how. Tried it several times